# Udev rule: test if a certain device property is defined

Tags: udev

I'm writing `udev` rules to mount usb drive on raspbian and I need to check if the property `ID_FS_TYPE` is defined, whatever the value is.
What I have so far is:

```
ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="usb-storage", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="?*", SUBSYSTEM=="block"
```

However this does not trigger. If I remove the star than it triggers twice upon insertion, but I need it to trigger once to call `pmount $DEVNAME`.
I've tried to replace `ID_FS_TYPE` with `ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition"`, but that works only for some filesystems like `ntfs` and `ext4`, but does not work for `FAT`.

Comment: I cannot replicate that behavior on a `systemd v.239` archlinux setup.  Works fine (triggers only once). FWIW, the following also works (triggers only once): `ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}!="|?"` that is, trigger only when the `ID_FS_TYPE` is *either* empty or one-char long. For the record, using `ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}==""` (that is, trigger only when `ID_FS_TYPE` is empty) also works.

Comment: Replace _either_ with _neither_... :)

Comment: But I need it to be not empty, that is one or more chars long

Comment: Yes, as I said, _your code works fine here_...